# Bootsrap: how can I put two rows side by side only on large screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two div which take 100% width on mobile screen. On large screen I would like them to take only 50% of the width and display them in the same row (like the inline-block property). I tried a lot of things in the CSS but nothing worked so far. Thanks a lot.

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="about">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> 
     <h1 class="middle-align">About</h1>
   </div>

   </div> <!--row-->
  </div> <!--about-->

<div class="container-fluid" id="about-content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <p>Some content about me</p>
  </div>

 </div> <!--row-->
</div> <!--about-content-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your columns into a single row, as shown below. For small screens, the columns will wrap into two lines. For larger screens, you'll have two columns side by side.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="about">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> 
            <h1 class="middle-align">About</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <p>Some content about me</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!--row-->
</div> <!--about-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine! I still have some troubles adjusting the height of the two div though. I set the height of the container-fluid of 100% but now the div are only taking the height of the content inside it...

Comment: I found the answer in another post) I managed to set the height of my two div equal to to the height of my container (100%) doing this                     div{
  height : 100vh;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS3 Conditional Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

   /* CSS Goes here! */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is nested `row`. Do this:

```
 <div class="container>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> 
         <h1 class="middle-align">About</h1>
       </div>

       </div> <!--row-->
    </div> <!--end of col-->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       <p>Some content about me</p>
      </div>
     </div> <!--row-->
    </div><!--end of col-->
    </div> <!--end of parent row-->
</div>
```

Comment: Your first row isn't within a container (and the class is missing the closing quote). See the intro to http://getbootstrap.com/css/ - "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding." The other containers should then be redundant.

Comment: I was just giving an example but thanks for pointing out the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" id="about"> 
       <h1 class="middle-align">About</h1>
      </div><!--about-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" id="about-content">
        <p>Some content about me</p>
      </div><!--about-content-->
  </div> <!--row-->
</div><!--container-fluid-->
```